# Bootstrap 3 validation not working

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know what's wrong with my contact form it says

```
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

[MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7gWQz/)

but I just copy this code

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mapb_1990/hTPY7/7/)

Any ideas what's wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: here is your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7gWQz/2/  working, you must check jQuery in jsFiddle

Comment: wow thanks! but I don't know why it is not working in my site :( I do have jquery there

Comment: You welcome :) anytime!

Answer (score 2):

Under Framework and Extensions, add jQuery, then re-run.

Answer (score 0):

Validate requires the form to use the post method, just edit your form tag like this

```
 <form id="contactus" name="contactus" method="post">
```

and it should work